# How to get clean output from easyocr

Tags: python, opencv, automatic-license-plate-recognition

This is from a opencv+easyocr number plate recognition script opencv crops the image to number plate and gives,clean great output to the easyocr. but what are these bunch of numbers its reading

`result = reader.readtext(opencv(mypath))`

*Result:  [([[0, 0], [163, 0], [163, 31], [0, 31]], 'SPHJ > 3764', 0.5565279612963627)]*

I know I can get a clean output by this but the thing is it differs from a picture to picture.
is there any way only to get the number plate

`result = result[0][-2]`

*Result:  SPHJ > 3764*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [stated in the docs](https://github.com/jaidedai/easyocr):

> The output will be in a list format, each item represents a bounding
> box, the text detected and confident level, respectively.

It's the coordinates of the box where the text is located. And the last item is the confidence level.

- `[[0, 0], [163, 0], [163, 31], [0, 31]]` -> the coordinates of the 4
  corners
- `'SPHJ > 3764'` -> the text
- `0.5565279612963627` -> confidence level

Just use `result[0][1]` to get the text. Note, result may have multiple text boxes detect, so you need to access by index or iterate over it.

```
for item in result:
    print(item[1])
```

Comment: so i need to run a loop to result[0][1]->result[1][1] like that right but how do i know that "if" the output have got 2 or more locations

Comment: I edited my answer to include sample of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is to get "pure" texts without position and confidence, then simply add 'detail=0' to readtext()

```
result = reader.readtext(opencv(mypath), detail=0)
# output: result = ['SPHJ > 3764'] or multiple items if the image contains more texts
```